# PHP session expiry

Tags: php, session

When a PHP session starts and is initialized with something like `$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();` does this hold the current time until the session is destroyed or until the browser is closed?

Comment: Yes it will. Why don't you try it yourself ?

Comment: Search "php session lifetime".

Comment: +1 for being a reasonable question... even if you were too lazy to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It holds the timestamp you assigned to it *at the time* you did it.

This value is kept till the session is destroyed (either by you or the client by closing his browser).

Answer (score 0):

It will stored the value of time() when you assigned it  until the session is destroyed .....

By default a session lasts until the user closes their browser. This can be changed in the php.ini file by change the 0 in `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` to be the number of seconds you want the session to last, or by using `session_set_cookie_params()`

Answer (score 0):

Session always destroy when browser is closed and you can also destroy it via `session_destroy` or `session_unset`